# Theano 0.10:　Can not use cuDNN on context None: cannot compile with cuDNN

Tags: theano

I just updated theano to 0.10 version with pip:

```
pip install --no-deps git+https://github.com/Theano/Theano.git#egg=Theano
```

But it cannot be imported successfully, with the error message as follows:

```
Can not use cuDNN on context None: cannot compile with cuDNN. 
We got this error: c:\users\yl~1\appdata\local\temp\try_flags_jbgv_m.c:4:19:　　

fatal error: cudnn.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated. 　　
Mapped name None to device cuda: GeForce 940M (0000:01:00.0)
```

I haven't configured theano to use cudnn. I feel theano should works without it.

My .theanorc is:
[image]

Without the .theanorc file, theano works fine.

I have also posted this issue at:
https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/6063#issuecomment-310064365

The best solution I have is to bypass cudnn by add in the .theanorc:

```
[dnn]
enabled = False
```

but at the price of the decreased computation speed

Comment: Same problem here.